# AR/ARMA model - test residual for independence or lack of correlation

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, iid

Shumway and Stoffer (2017), a great book that I highly recommend, define an AR(p) model as $x_t=\phi_1 x_{t-1}+\phi_2 x_{t-2}+...+\phi_p x_{t-p}+w_t$, where $w_t$~$wn(0,\sigma_w^2)$; $w_t$ is **not** assumed to be Normally distributed. Notice that means $w_t$ is white noise (uncorrelated) not i.i.d. noise (independent). The ARMA process is also defined with white noise residuals. Yet on page 139 as part of model diagnostics they state:

"*If the model fits well, the standardized residuals should behave as an i.i.d. sequence with mean 0 and variance 1.... Unless the time series is Gaussian, it is not enough that the residuals are uncorrelated*".

In my mind, there is a clear inconsistency here. We've assumed that the model has uncorrelated errors, not independent errors; it therefore seems necessary to test for correlation only.

1. Is there an inconsistency here?
2. I checked a number of textbooks and I've only seen ARMA models defined with white noise errors. This makes me wonder, in R when fitting a model with the **sarima** command of the *astsa* package (written by the authors of the above mentioned book) what is assumed of the error term? Independence or lack of correlation?

Comment: @Aksakal: thank you, good point; your comment prompted me to add some more elements to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the 4th edition of the book, but the answer is No, there's no contradiction because authors clearly state that they sometimes use *more restrictive* condition of IID, instead of a simply *white noise*. For instance, in Example 1.8 of 3rd edition they say

> We will, at times, also require the noise to be independent and
> identically distributed (iid) random variables with mean 0 and
> variance $\sigma^2_w$.

The reason to use more restrictive condition can vary from didactic (easier to explain and derive certain results) to meaningful, such as obtaining sharper results under limited circumstances.

Comment: Any thoughts on what is assumed by the sarima command in the astsa package?

Comment: I believe they use Gaussian likelihood function by default

Comment: oh found it https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sarima/sarima.pdf page 49 looks like they assume just White Noise, not Gaussian White Noise

Comment: @ColorStatistics, I would expect them to assume Gaussian likelihood as Aksakal said. In estimation of ARMA models, this comes in handy.

Comment: @RichardHardy: That makes sense, but page 49 of the documentation of sarima does not mention a Normally distributed error term and the error term assumed to be just White Noise.

Comment: @ColorStatistics, while I understand what you are saying, "does not mention" is not the same as "does not do". You can do and not mention. They seem to be using state-space stuff, and that is usually done with a Gaussian likelihood.

Comment: @RichardHardy: I will counter with "comes in handy to assume Normality" does not mean "will assume Normality"

Comment: @ColorStatistics, that might have been poor phrasing on my side. You are right in general, but I would not advise you to bet on that in this case. I would be curious to know if you ever find out they did not use Gaussian likelihood in their estimations (explicitly or implicitly).

Comment: @RichardHardy: I agree. I am surprised it takes us this long to figure out what is assumed. Whether or not they assume Normality should be stated upfront. How else is someone using sarima supposed to know whether to test for independent residuals or just uncorrelated residuals?!

Comment: In this book they use Gaussian likelihood almost everywhere, plus it is focused on linear models. Hence I’d be very surprised if they didn’t use Gaussian likelihood in the package by default. In fact I can’t recall any popular package that doesn’t do this

Comment: I see. I guess I learned that to assume Normality for the residuals in ARIMA models is such popular practice that it is sometimes assumed without mention.

Comment: And yet there are a number of estimation methodologies that do not require the Normality assumption: take Kalman filter, Yule-Walker, the Innovations algorithm, or Burg algorithms for example.

Comment: Kalman fillers are default in state space representations in software